# Is there a difference between "also" and "too" in the following sentences?

Tags: difference

Is there a difference between "also" and "too" in the following sentences? or it's just a matter of style? If it is just a matter of style  what's consider more colloquial and what's more formal?

> a) This product  has two colors **too**.
>
> b) This product has **also** two colors.

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers would use a slightly different word order when using **also**

> This product also has two colors.

Both sentences mean the same thing, however I would certainly use the *also* form. This is a matter of style. I see also as a better choice because:

1. trivially, **two** and **too** have more or less the same pronunciation, so *two orders too* sounds odd
2. The **also** comes earlier in the sentence, and so emphasisers the continuity of thought from the previous sentence.

Note however that **also** and **too** are not quite interchangeable when used in a slightly different way. In a case where we are talking about our own preferences

> I like apples.

Both of the following work:

> I also like pears
>
> I like pears too.

and this does **not** when following *I like apples*

> I too like pears

However when are comparing our preferences with another person's preferences

> Peter likes apples

Then **too** works well, we can use either ordering

> I too like apples
>
> I like apples too

though the first one sounds better, we emphasise our similarity with Peter.

and here the use of also is not correct, we can't use **also** to modify the subject of the sentence: **I**

> I also like apples (**wrong in this context**)

Comment: This is a great answer, except for the very last bit.  "Peter likes Apples.  I also like apples" is perfectly correct, and means the same thing as "too" in this context.  Note that "also" and "too" can both be used before the verb or at the end of the phrase, but it is more common for "also" to be used before the verb, and more common for "too" to be used at the end of the phrase.  Switching the places is often used for emphasis. ("I too like apples" is stronger than "I like apples too")

Comment: This is an interesting comment. I wonder why I (still) feel that "also" is not quite right in this context.